# How to embed devtool in code to verify network throttling using Java code

Tags: java, bandwidth, throttling

I have an issue in embedding devtool code in for verifying network throttling using Java code on my Windows machine. I have searched for the same using many websites but none of the code is actually working. Any help on this front would be super appreciated. Thanks!

http://wicg.github.io/netinfo/ link already referred but its not functional.

Comment: Can you show us the code you tried and error you got?

Comment: Below is snippet of dummy code where I tried adding line to get network connection type:

        String type = navigator.connection.type;
 
Error: navigator cannot be resolved to a variable. I am not sure what import statement should be used to make it working.

I referered to link provided above. This line of code is written inside any web page. Hope that helps.